# Is how to avoid legal issues in scope

Tags: discussion, scope

See this post [if-i-turn-the-real-money-into-fake-currency-will-it-still-be-gambling-app](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11321/if-i-turn-the-real-money-into-fake-currency-will-it-still-be-gambling-app/28290?noredirect=1#comment50486_28290).

I proposed a business model that avoids legal issues.  I received a comment that is not legal advice and does not belong on the site.

I my mind how to avoid legal issues is in scope here.  I am more interested in  advice on how to stay out of legal issues than wait for a legal issue before consulting an attorney.

I get advice from a tax attorney and their advice is based on law but there is no discussion on the law.

From the tour an example question.  "How can I take back my sovereignty from the American government and start my own micro nation?"  Would an imaginative answer that avoids the legal issues without fighting the law directly not be a valid answer?

Please vote, comment, and or answer

Answer (score 2):

I would not oppose deleting the tag "legal-advice" because I see that it could encourage people to think that such questions are on-topic. However, I don't know if there is a way to *ban* a tag, and there's little point in playing whack-a-mole with tags.

The question asks about what the law is, not "how do I reach this goal". The only on-topic answer addresses the legal question, and not some hypothesized reason for asking the question. Your answer simply does not answer the question that was asked. There is a "reason to delete" flag for things that are not answers to the questions asked, and I notice that your post was not deleted though technically it should have been. Perhaps the idea was that you might take some time and answer the question that was asked.

Comment: OK.   Confuses me the question was allow to stand.   To me the question is asking legal advice.

Comment: OK.  Not to argue but I would say the sample in scope tour question is asking for legal advice.  "How can I take back my sovereignty from the American government and start my own micro nation?"

Comment: The only `legal-advice` tag I see is here on meta, where it most certainly belongs, as evidenced by the OP's persistent questioning: it tags Q&A devoted to explaining what constitutes "legal advice" and why that's off-topic.

Comment: Well that makes the tag issue even more irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Legal *advice* is explicitly off-topic.

This site is devoted to Q&A about law.  The problem with your answer is that it not only provides no legal *information*, but also itself begs a number of legal questions – e.g., "How is it legal to gamble on poker in Oregon? According to what law?" and, "Does this *possible business model* change the legal nature of the transactions?"

You could probably bring your answer on-topic by providing information that addresses those questions (if not the original question).

Comment: I fail to understand how an example business model of skirting legal issues is off scope.   I don't think you mean this "Legal advice is explicitly off-topic."  From the tour  "How can I take back my sovereignty from the American government and start my own micro nation?" is an example in scope question.  An imaginative answer that avoided direct legal issues would be out of scope?

Comment: @paparazzo: See [meta-tag:legal-advice].  And an answer that contained an illustration would be fine, if it were even vaguely clear that it was grounded in some legal reality.

Comment: Really?  The site is law.stackexchange.com, there is a legal-advice tag, and yet legal advice is explicitly off-topic.   That aside, I fail to understand how it can both be off topic for being business advice and off topic for being legal advice.  Again would an imaginative answer on sovereignty that avoided direct legal issues  be out of scope?